# On-line security tools?

Tags: 11.04, security

Are there tools built into "Ubuntu" (or possibly within the repositories) to help me secure my on-line information.

Comment: What do you mean by "online information"? Information hosted by a hosting provider?

Comment: The different browsers come with built in settings that you can djust to make your experience on the web safer, filters, ad blockers, etc.

Comment: I'm thinking about password management, such as password generators, encryption etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - many! You could compile and build any of the linux tools, or if you like prepackaged solutions you can use apt-get to install packages such as the following:

- **gpw** password generator
- **keepass2** password safe
- **john** password strength tool
- **gpg** encryption

Look in the apt gui - a large list of security tools are listed there